# Full width of col-md-10 when using col-md-2 for sidebar bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add background color for nav-header, and since it is within col-md-10, it won't take full width when sidebar (col-md-2) is closed.
I tried to wrap it inside another div, but it doesn't work, I can't override col-md-10 rules. Is there any way to do this?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
        <div class="col-md-2 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width hidden" id="sidebar">
            <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">

                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 2</span></a>
                <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 3 </span></a><a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 4</span></a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 5</span></a>

            </div>
        </div>
        <main class="col-md-10 float-left">
            <div class="nav-header">
                <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x py-2 p-1"></i></a>
                <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" height="45" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="page-header">
                <h2>Bootstrap 4 Sidebar Menu</h2>
            </div>

            <hr>

        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using the flat CSS file for bootstrap or are you compiling the SCSS yourself?

Comment: using bootstrap cdn scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a positioned pseudo-element to imitate a background.

```
.col-md-10 .nav-header{
  position: relative;

}

.col-md-10 .nav-header::after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  background: red;
  width:calc(100vw - 30px);
}
```

```css
.col-md-10 .nav-header {
  position: relative;
}

.col-md-10 .nav-header::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  width: calc(100vw - 30px);
  z-index: -1
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row d-flex d-md-block flex-nowrap wrapper">
    <div class="col-md-2 float-left col-1 pl-0 pr-0 collapse width hidden" id="sidebar">
      <div class="list-group border-0 card text-center text-md-left">

        <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-film"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 2</span></a>
        <a href="#menu3" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sidebar" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 3 </span></a><a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed"
          data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 4</span></a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-inline-block collapsed" data-parent="#sidebar"><i class="fa fa-list"></i> <span class="d-none d-md-inline">Item 5</span></a>

      </div>
    </div>
    <main class="col-md-10 float-left">
      <div class="nav-header">
        Nav header content
        <a href="#" data-target="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa fa-navicon fa-2x py-2 p-1"></i></a>
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand"><img src="img/logo.png" height="45" alt=""></a>
      </div>
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2>Bootstrap 4 Sidebar Menu</h2>
      </div>

      <hr>

    </main>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tried this also, it overlaps the content, I just get a rel line over header content. I've tried with z-index, still not working

Comment: Sounds like you haven't set the height. Z-index should work.

Answer (score 0):

That's tricky.  Unless you can use the sass functions to build your columns, you'll have to override the styles for that particular `.col-md-10`.  Maybe something like this?

```
#sidebar:not(.show) + [class*=col-] {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tro4uwq9/) (Note: I'm using jsfiddle because stack snippets is blocking a part of bootstrap's js and failing to execute the part for opening or closing the menu)

## Edit

For those curious, the SCSS way to do it would be to [use a mixin](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#mixins)

Your SCSS might look like this:

```
#sidebar + main {
  @include make-col(12);
}
#sidebar.show + main {
  @include make-col(10);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it looks ok, but it doesn't run smoothly. It looks like it breaks when toggling

Comment: @frontendgirl "Looks like it breaks".  Can you elaborate? What specifically is wrong with it when it toggles?

Comment: it doesn't open and close smoothly. For a millisecond everything disappears, like it is refreshed. Other than that, this is an excellent solution.

Comment: @frontendgirl That's because this transition is intended for an animation.  It has a delay to allow one to be added using CSS.  That part would still need to be implemented.